# Define $g :\ell_2 \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}n$. Is $g$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Define  $g  :\ell_2 \to \mathbb R$ by

$$g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}n $$

Is $g$ continuous?

I need to solve this but I could not see how to tackle it? any hints or suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked for bounded sequences with unbounded image?

Comment: $\ell_2$ is a Hilbert space. What representations have continuous linear functionals on a Hilbert space?

Comment: Show us some thought or partial progress please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $g$ is linear. A linear operator is continuous if and only if it is continuous at $x=0$, if and only if it is bounded.

Try to find a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x$:
$$
|g(x)|\leq C \|x\|
$$

Answer (score 3):

A linear functional on a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ is continuous if and only if it is Lipschitz, and thus if and only if there exists $M\geq 0$ such that $\|f(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$ for all $x$.

The norm on the real Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}^*)$ is associated to a dot product which verifies some inequality.